# Why does google-chrome not rendering maxjax when printing to pdf from the command line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line, printing

google-chrome has the ability to print to a pdf file from the command line working in headless mode:

```
google-chrome --headless --print-to-pdf file.html
```

However, when I try to use chrome in a script for html to pdf conversion using this facility it looks like items rendered from javascript are not rendered at all. I am seeing this with maxjax expressions that are rendered correctly if I print from chrome, but not rendered at all if I print using chrome from the command line.

Any clue? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

--print-to-pdf also requires --virtual-time-budget= to assure that chrome does not print *before* it has completed its work on the page.